# omitting work experience

Tags: resume, job-search, ethics

I was fired last year for reporting sexual harassment and discrimination with the company I was with for 6 years. I filed a lawsuit and when I google myself it shows up.

I am struggling to find work and am not sure if this is why.

I have started using my maiden name on applications and it has helped me get a few interviews but I still have not found work. I am experienced, educated (masters degree) and hard worker (always on time, stay late, cover or take on responsibilities of others). I was awarded top performer on my team every year I have been there.

I need some help on what to do.

My questions are:

- Should I omit the company from my resume altogether. I can replace it with the freelance consulting I have done over the last few years.
- Is this deceitful because I don't want to be deceitful.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps others will disagree, but I'd say it's unlikely that this lawsuit is still the root cause of you not obtaining work with your maiden name, so long as the following are true:

- The lawsuit doesn't come up in a search using your maiden name;
- The lawsuit isn't one that's well known, where others may have heard of it;
- The lawsuit doesn't cause (directly or indirectly) you to receive a bad reference.

The last one is perhaps the most likely to still be causing you issues. If you haven't already, then put "references available on request" on your CV, and try to make sure you have a more amicable contact in the previous company that can give you a good reference. A manager is obviously best, but if you had a supportive coworker there, then give them as a reference instead (a good reference from a coworker is going to be much better than a bad one from a manager.)

Answer (score 1):

### No

You should absolutely not omit this kind of work experience. 6 years of work is huge and replacing it with "freelance consulting" is definitely deceitful.

You don't know wether your are having trouble finding a new job because of getting fired from your last job.

When talking about it during interviews, start by concentrating on the actual work and tasks you did for 6 years.

You will eventually have to explain why you were fired. Don't get too much into the details, stick to the facts and don't try to find excuses. You need to show that it was an unfortunate turn of events and that you are now over this and ready to work on new interesting things.

This is the kind of experience that an eventual employer will definitely found about at some point in time. If they also find out that you are practically lying to them and hiding information, things can only go worse.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is deceitful would be a moral or ethical question and would be subjective based on anyone's varied experiences.

Morally speaking, if the reason is as you state, it is likely far more people would consider your actions just than if the reason for omitting the information was related to some situation for which you were at fault for making occur.

Ethical considerations would likely be subject more to the norms and rules, official and unofficial, if any, of the type of work you are trying to do / the profession within which you work.

Legally, other than where the job you're applying for has processes subject to statutes (such as government employees' applications, particularly when applying for any given security clearance), you might be okay, but I don't know that because it would depend on local laws, which jurisdiction you're in, etc. - (not legal advice, just a guess - consult an attorney if you think you need legal advice!).

Comment: Agreed. But people like OP, whom I can only take at her word since I know nothing about her, should not have to suffer due to others' actions.

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're making. This isn't about them taking her at her word. This is about whether she should omit a section of her resume.

Comment: fair enough, deleting my comments